# GridSearchCV returning results not in the param grid

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I have defined my parameter grid and gridsearch here. The weird thing is, the output does not include any of the parameter options I set. E.g. max features has been set to auto.

Have I done something wrong?

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

param_grid = {
'bootstrap': [True],
'max_depth': [90, 100, 110],
'max_features': [2, 3, 10, 20],
'min_samples_leaf': [3, 4, 5, 10],
'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 8, 10, 12],
'n_estimators': [10, 20, 50, 60, 70]
}

model = RandomForestClassifier()

# Instantiate the grid search model
best = GridSearchCV(estimator = model, param_grid = param_grid, 
cv = 3, n_jobs = -1, verbose = 2)

best.fit(x, y.ravel())
```

[image]

Comment: You're wondering why the GridSearchCV has printed `max_features='auto'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take the return value of the `best.fit()` function.

```py
fitted_grid = best.fit(x, y.ravel()) 
best_classifier = fitted_grid.best_estimator_
best_parameters = fitted_grid.best_params_
```

I did not see that part in your code snippet, so maybe that's where you were missing something ?

Comment: ah, so best.score_ was giving me the correct accuracy, but I hadn't handled getting the best parameters out.  Thanks for the help!!